# What do these screws on the side of Forever Door do?

Tags: storm-door

I want to paint my Forever Storm Door.   It has screws in slots on the sides.   I don't know what they do and don't really want to paint over them.

Does anyone know what they do and can I remove them without messing up the door?

[image]

Edit:  There are a total of eight screws on this side, 4 above and 4 below the handle.  There are a total of ten screws on the hinge side.

Comment: Are they connected to a sweep? Take a photo showing what they're connected to top and bottom and it will be much easier to decipher. Is there one of both sides of the door?

Comment: Have you checked whether the manufacturer has installation instructions on their web page? That might explain the purpose of those screws.

Comment: @keshlam  Yep, checked the manufacturer's web site and I have the installation instructions...no mention of them.   I left a message there...but it's a holiday weekend.

Comment: @matt.  I edited my post.   There is a stationary sweep attached to the door (already removed in preparation).

Comment: Prudence dictates that you do not remove these screws without knowing their purpose. Put masking tape on them and the slots to protect them from paint spray. (Perhaps peel the tape off immediately after painting while the paint is still wet?)  A speculation is that the glass panel is removalble from the frame. If you would remove them all at the same time, the glass panel might fall out!

Comment: @JimStewart  The door stores the glass panel and screen internally.  I have already removed both.   I'm definitely not going to remove the screws unless I know what they are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about this door https://helpcenter.andersenwindows.com/stormdoor/s/article/EMCO-Forever-Series-Traditional-Store-In-Door-Storm-Door-Product-Overview

There is an article about painting them https://helpcenter.andersenwindows.com/stormdoor/s/article/Painting-EMCO-Forever-Series-Traditional-or-Crossbuck-Store-in-Door-Storm-Door-Panels

But it says only doors manufactured before Oct 2002 can be painted. It mentions that the screws need to be loosened before painting and then retightened (with a small gap) after paint is dry. They are used to allow thermal expansion of the door panels.